# File is empty after reading its size

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, boto3

I want to read the size of a file before uploading it to S3 in order to check if there is enough available storage left. The following code works. However the file is empty when it is uploaded to S3. If I delete the part that checks the size of the file it is uploaded properly. Is there another way to get the file size? The file comes from an upload form of a HTML page and I'm uploading it directly to S3 without saving it to the server first.

```
availablestorage = getavailablestorage() #gets the available storage in bytes
latestfile = request.files['filetoupload'] #get the file from the HTML form
latestfile.seek(0,2)
latestsize = latestfile.tell() #this gets the size of the file
if availablestorage < latestsize:
  return "No space available. Delete files."
bucketname = request.form.get('spaceforupload')
conn = boto3.client('s3')
conn.upload_fileobj(latestfile, bucketname, latestfile.filename)
return redirect(url_for('showspace', spacename=bucketname))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course, you just seeked to the end to get the size, now `latestfile` handle current position is "end of file".

Just do:

```
latestfile.seek(0)
```

before running `conn.upload_fileobj`. That should work.